# Excel Reference next row in array when logic is false

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I want tabs in my Excel sheet to reference fields in a different page if criteria is met; if the criteria is not met, I want to skip that row, and move to the next row where the criteria is met.

My database houses individuals who have been diagnosed with cancer (breast and prostate). I want the breast tracking page to only populate individuals who have been diagnosed with breast cancer (referencing the “Participant Information” sheet; column D). Currently I used an `IF` statement to populate this information, but my sheet populates empty rows because those rows are prostate cancer (meaning they do not meet the `IF` statement criteria).

I have found this formula:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX('Participant Information'!A:A,SMALL(IF('Participant Information'!$D$2:$D$300="Breast",ROW('Participant Information'!$D$2:$D$300)),ROWS(1:1))),"")}
```

But I cannot understand how it works. It also it not working for my purpose.

TL;DR: I need to reference cells on a separate tab, without having blank rows when the criteria isn't met. I think of the "Next Record" function that is used in Mail Merge.

Comment: Look into `FILTER()` function it would be easy to understand. And if you are not using the `MS365` per your tag, then use `INDEX()` & `AGGREGATE()` function, you can exclude blanks as well.

Comment: May be you need a amend in your present formula as it seems, try this one: `=IFERROR(INDEX('Participant Information'!A$2:A$300,SMALL(IF('Participant Information'!D$2:D$300="Breast",ROW('Participant Information'!D$2:D$300)-ROW(D$2)+1)),ROWS(1:1))),"")`

Comment: With `AGGREGATE()` you wont need to hit the `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER` while exiting the edit mode which you are presently doing using your current formula, that said: `=IFERROR(INDEX('Participant Information'!A$2:A$300,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW('Participant Information'!D$2:D$300)-ROW(D$2)+1)/('Participant Information'!D$2:D$300="Breast"),ROWS(1:1))),"")` --> `15` means `SMALL()` while `6` means to ignore errors values. Lemme know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

As commented above with the said functions once can accomplish desired output, here is a sample data, which reflects the outcome needed:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D3</kbd>

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Participant Information'!$B$5:$B$15,
 AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW('Participant Information'!$B$5:$E$15)-ROW('Participant Information'!$B$5)+1)/
 ('Participant Information'!$E$5:$E$15=Records!$C$2),ROWS(Records!D$2:D2))),"")
```

---

- `AGGREGATE()` function is used to perform the aggregate calculations, here it is used for `SMALL()` which represents `15`
- The second parameter in the above function is `6` which means to ignore error values.
- The third parameter is a array values where
  `(ROW('Participant Information'!$B$5:$E$15)-ROW('Participant Information'!$B$5)+1)` calculates the row numbers with the said range.
  `('Participant Information'!$E$5:$E$15=Records!$C$2)` checks if the corresponding column in `E` matches with the criteria here it is `Breast` in cell `C2`. Next, an array is created by dividing the `ROW()` returns by the criteria returns to get only those which are met i.e `TRUE` while the others which dont meet are divided by `0` hence returns error and are ignored.
- `ROWS(Records!D$2:D2)` returns the smallest value,
- `INDEX()` function returns the name from the range based on the smallest value i.e. the row number.
- `IFERROR()` is used to ignore any error values down the line if there are no more retrieve any records.

---

So, that said for your sheet, it would be

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Participant Information'!A$2:A$300,
  AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW('Participant Information'!D$2:D$300)-ROW(D$2)+1)/
 ('Participant Information'!D$2:D$300="Breast"),ROWS(1:1))),"")
```

---

Using `FILTER()` it will be simple and easy as well:

```
=FILTER('Participant Information'!A$2:A$300,
 'Participant Information'!D$2:D$300="Breast","Not Found")
```

---

**[Sample_Data_With_Formulas](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2ckjtq8e7hXlP1VFws?e=kHTWJy)**